# Improve Performance of Matlab Function

Tags: performance, matlab, math, matrix, vectorization

I would like to improve one of my simple matlab functions.
Is there any arithmetic way to implement this function? I think that would perform much better.

```
function img_output = cutchannels(img_input, min, max)
[r c l] = size(img_input);
img_output = double(img_input);

for i = 1:r
    for j = 1:c
        for k = 1:l
            if(img_output(i:j:k)> max)
                img_output(i:j:k) = max;
            elseif(img_output(i:j:k) < min)
                img_output(i:j:k) = min;
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Why are you looking up `img_output(i:j:k)` every iteration? That's pretty strange. It would make more sense if you accessed `img_output(i,j,k)`. The for loops are probably entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Cause I wan't to check every pixel value in my image if it's above max or below min.

Comment: You are not checking every pixel in your image.

Comment: -1: I didn't find any good news in this question, now I'm even more depressed than when I started reading it.

Comment: Was any of the answers useful to you?

Comment: input: 512x512x3 matrix - my own cutchannel: 0.326s - angainor's cutchannel: 0,019s - rody's cutchannel: 0,004s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it way shorter:

```
function img = cutchannels(img, min_val, max_val)
    img = min( max(double(img),min_val), max_val );
end
```

which begs the question on why you would want to implement this in a function at all (e.g., why no use this one-liner everywhere you need it?)

As a word of advice: `min` and `max` are names of built-in Matlab functions. Although legal, it is poor practice to use them as variable names as well. For example, what does

```
M = max(max, 5)
```

mean, when `max` is a variable name? Are you indexing `max` the variable, or callng `max` the function, with `max` the variable as input? It's confusing to you, as well as to Matlab's parser. Advice: use other variable names like `minimum` or `maximum`, as in the function above.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, this is what you want to do

```
function img_output = cutchannels(img_input, min, max)

img_output = double(img_input);
img_output(img_output>max) = max;
img_output(img_output<min) = min;

end
```

First of all, I think there is a mistake in your indexing: `img_output(i:j:k)` should in fact read `img_output(i,j,k)` - this is the way to index your 3D array.

The above is a standard way to use *logical indices* in MATLAB ([read about it here](http://www.mathworks.se/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html)). The statement

```
img_output>max
```

returns a 0/1 array of size equal to the size of `img_output`, where all elements in `img_output` that are larger than `max` are 1. You can then use this matrix as an index in `img_output`

```
img_output(img_output>max)
```

this chooses only those entries of `img_output` for which the logical indices are equal to 1. You can then assign them any value  you want

```
img_output(img_output>max) = max
```

or, as a side note, do any other operation on them, e.g.

```
img_output(img_output>max) = img_output(img_output>max).^2;
```